# Is there the way to change white color of a main page mask of "react-native-drawer" component?

Tags: react-native

As I see in android applications almost all drawers in open state makes a black "mask" above main content.

white mask in "react-native-drawer:

[image: white mask in "react-native-drawer" (or it is just some alpha properties is applied...)]

black color example:

[image: black color example]

It is possible to change the color of this "mask" in "react-native-drawer" component to black?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was looking for the same thing and found a solution at [GitHub](https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer/issues/162#issuecomment-232825970).

```
tweenHandler={ratio => ({
   main: {
      opacity: 1,
   },
   mainOverlay: {
      opacity: ratio / 2,
      backgroundColor: 'black',
   },
})}
```

Tested it out and here's what I got (made it pink for visibility):

```
<Drawer
   tweenHandler={ratio => ({
     main: {
       opacity: 1,
     },
     mainOverlay: {
       opacity: ratio / 2,
       backgroundColor: 'pink',
     },
   })}
   ref={(ref) => { this._drawer = ref; }}
   content={ navigationView }
   side="right"
   panOpenMask={.25}
>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much :) 

Had this 

```
                main: { opacity:(2-ratio)/2 },
                mainOverlay: {
                  opacity: ratio,
                  backgroundColor: 'transparent'
                }
```

And wondered why on iOS I could no longer see background content, but on Android I could.

Thanks anyway :)